# Gerar valor aleatório com formatação

Tags: php, javascript, md5

Como posso gerar uma string aleatória com uma determinada formatação? Estou fazendo com criptografia em PHP mas não consigo formatar os valores.

Queria que gerasse de acordo com o seguinte exemplo:

```
A9MDY3-X6S
```

Meu código está somente criando um `md5` mas queria gerar um texto como no exemplo acima.

Meu código:

```
<?php md5(date("d/m/Y H:i:s")); ?>
```

**Nota:** Gostaria de realizar em JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

olá, você pode usar uma funcão como esta:

```
    function gerarCombinacao() {

        $combinacao = chr(rand(97,122));
        $combinacao .= chr(rand(97,122));
        $combinacao .= chr(rand(97,122));
        $combinacao .= "-";
        $combinacao .= rand(0,9);
        $combinacao .= rand(0,9);
        $combinacao .= rand(0,9);

        return $combinacao; 
    }
```

O result da função a cima sera ex; **asd-962**

onde ela vai gerar string com numeros aleatorios de `0-9` e letras de `a-z`

Os tipos dos caracteres dentro do CHR pode ser verificado em https://www.ascii-code.com/

Answer (score 2):

Com `php`:

```
<?php
$hash = strtoupper(md5(date("d/m/Y H:i:s")));
$hash = substr($hash,0,9); //Corta a string para 9 digitos;
$hash = substr_replace($hash, '-', 6, 0 ); //Insere o sinal na posicao indicada;
echo $hash;
```

Com `JavaScript`:

```js
    function randomString() {
     var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZ";
     var length = 9;
     var randomstring = '';
     for (var i=0; i < length; i++) {
      var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
      randomstring += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
     }
     var output = [randomstring.slice(0, 6), '-', randomstring.slice(6)].join('');
     document.randform.randomfield.value = output;
    }
```

```html
<form name="randform">
<input type="button" value="Create Random String" onClick="randomString();">&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="randomfield" value="">
</form>
```

Fontes: [How to Create Random Numbers & Characters](https://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/number/random.html), [Inserting string at position x of another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364881/inserting-string-at-position-x-of-another-string).

Answer (score 1):

```js
    function gerarNumeroAleatorio() {
    
      var texto = "";
      var valores= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
      var tamanho = 9;
    
      for (var i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
        texto += valores.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * valores.length));
    
      console.log(texto.substr(0,6) + "-" + texto.substr(6,10));
      
      }
```

```html
    
    <button onClick="gerarNumeroAleatorio();">GERAR</button>
```

> Queria que gerasse de acordo com o seguinte exemplo: `A9MDY3-X6S`.

O que levei em consideração foi gerar uma `String` com valores aleatórios misturando valores alfabéticos e numéricos.

A variável `valores`, possui toda diversidade dos possíveis valores aleatórios que devemos "sortear".
A variável tamanho(9) está referente à quantidade de caracteres que vamos ter no valor final(considere o ponto inicial como o índice 0).
E feito um loop e dentro dele os números/caractere aleatórios separados por um *hífen* na seguinte ordem: `6 dígitos(texto.substr(0,6) - 3 dígitos(texto.substr(6,10)`.